# Rails Ajax create.js.erb how to reload partial?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form successfully submitting data via ajax, but I can't figure out how to trigger an event after the ajax action. I'd like to reload the partial containing the form after a new record is submitted.

View

```
#container
  #partial
   <%= form_for [@qa, @newpdd], :remote => true do |f| %>
    ....
   <%= f.submit "add %>
```

PDD Controller

```
def create
@pdd = Pdd.create!(params[:pdd])
@pdd.qa_id = params[:qa_id]
@qa = Qa.find(params[:qa_id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @pdd.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@qa, :notice => 'Pdd was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @pdd, :status => :created, :location => @pdd }
    format.js
#    render :partial => pddsection
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @pdd.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$('#partial').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'pdds/partial') %>");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning the :remote => true condition in the form as demonstrated in this rails cast:

[Railscast 136](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery)

Everything now works as expected. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `<%=j %>` tag instead of `<%= escape_javascript() %>`, though they may be functionally similar.

Your code looks good. `:remote => true` should cause your browser to execute whatever javascript is returned by the server (in this case, create.js.erb). As a troubleshooting step, open up the developer console of your browser and look at the response you are getting from the ajax form submission. Is the correct view rendering? Is the javascript that ERB rendered correct?

If it looks good, copy and paste it in the javascript console. If that doesn't update the page, figure out what's wrong with it. Could be a bad selector or a syntax error.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in the developer console. Any suggestions on how to interrogate the console to figure out what response I'm getting?

Comment: if using firebug console it should return the response. You click on the request which will also return the response

Comment: It looks like I'm getting a 302 Found response on the Post request, followed by a 200 OK with the GET request. Seems right?

Comment: No, that isn't right. A 302 Found is a redirect. You should only be seeing a 200 OK. Check the URL that is being rendered by the `form_for` tag and verify that it is the correct URL for your `create` method. Try visiting the URL directly with your browser to make sure that your `routes.rb` file is configured correctly.

When you look at the rails server console when the 302 Found response happens, what controller is responding?